# i am running mvn clean install. checked with proxy, mirror , installed certificate still did not resolve

Tags: java, maven

I tried running `mvn clean install`. I checked with proxy, mirror , installed certificate but could not resolve the issue. Here is the error message:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help].
```

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment with a firewall/proxy that is doing man-in-the-middle shenanigans with SSL certificates?  Go to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 with your browser and check if the SSL certificate is the original (trusted by a well known CA) or has a CA from a proxy that needs to be installed.

Comment: yes, but i tried from outside,  logging out from customer pulse secure connection, still facong the same issue. i deleted .m2 repository, but seems everytime i am trying to run mvn install, the plugins are not getting downloaded. But i think its a customer laptop so the policies may still affect. not sure